# Vue+Firebase, не удается соеденится с БД

Tags: ubuntu, vue.js, firebase

Постоянно при любом развертывании приложения на VUE + FIREBASE, выдает ошибку. Сначала винил себя, но решил взять код нескольких 100% рабочих проектов. И все одно и то же.
Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на http://192.168.0.102:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1547050466259. (Причина: не удалось выполнить запрос CORS).

OS Ubuntu
Mozila 
Google chrome 
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А `curl` дёргает нормально?

Comment: Да, если бы его не отдавало. Приложение вообще, не разворачивалось бы.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что если написать `curl --verbose http://url` - что-то есть или нет?

Comment: Я только что протестировал, он получил connection.

Comment: Я правильно понял - с curl - ок, а с ff и gh - не ок?